# Why wrapper class in Java doesn't behave like a reference type?

Tags: java, class, types, reference, wrapper

I have a huge problem to understand why wrapper class in Java doesn't behave like a reference type.
Example:

```
Integer one = 10;
Integer two = one;
one = 20;
System.out.println(one);
System.out.println(two);
```

The output will be:

20

10

I thought that `two` will be 20 like in this example where I create my own class:

```
class OwnInteger {
        private int integer;

        public OwnInteger(int integer) {
            this.integer = integer;
        }

        public int getInteger() {
            return integer;
        }

        public void setInteger(int integer) {
            this.integer = integer;
        }
    }

    OwnInteger one = new OwnInteger(10);
    OwnInteger two = one;
    one.setInteger(20);
    System.out.println(one.getInteger());
    System.out.println(two.getInteger());
```

So the question, is Integer wrapper class special? Why does it behave as I have shown in my examples?

Comment: There's a big difference between `one = 20;` and `one.setInteger(20);`, and it has nothing to do with wrapper classes. `one = 20;` of the first snippet would be equivalent to `one = new OwnInteger(20);` in the second snippet.

Comment: These classes behave exactly like reference types, probably because they _are_ reference types. When you point one reference to a different object, you don't change the other pointer. The pointers are independent. It's only changes to an _object_ that are visible via any pointer to the same _object_. Remember that as the JLS says, Java "references ... are pointers".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly the behavior of a reference type. In your example, `two` references the same object as `one` after the assignment. However, re-assigning `one` a new object has no effect on `two`, which is the behavior that you see.

You will see the same behavior with other reference objects as well, for example

```
StringBuilder one = new StringBuilder("10");
StringBuilder two = one;
one = new StringBuilder("20");
// two still references StringBuilder with "10"
```

In order for a reference class to exhibit the behavior when changing one object also changes the other, the class needs to be *mutable*, like the `OwnInteger` class in your code, *and* the code needs to change the object, rather than reassigning it. Wrapper classes, such as `Integer`, are immutable, so you would not experience that behavior with them.

Answer (score 3):

> *I thought that two will be 20*...

nop, when you do this

```
Integer two = one;
one = 20;
```

you are actually assigning a new object to the variable `one` and variable `two` will no get updated with those changes...

to your class OwnInteger

```
OwnInteger one = new OwnInteger(10);
OwnInteger two = one;
one.setInteger(20);
```

they do what you expected because `one` and `two` are pointing to the same reference..

code `A` will be equivalent to

```
OwnInteger one = new OwnInteger(10);
OwnInteger two = one;
one = new OwnInteger(20); //one.setInteger(20);
```

Comment: "one and two are pointing to the same reference.." Wrong, they are pointing to the same _object_.

Answer (score 0):

```
one = 20;
```

using "boxing", and is actually equivalent to this:

```
one = Integer.valueOf(20);
```

In your case `valueOf` method create a new object and return a reference of that newly created object because previously not exist in cache.

For your own class `one` and `two` both reference variable are pointing to same object.

Comment: The same thing would have happened even without autoboxing, which is not the reason for the OP's observation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers so far all are at least partially wrong. The effect you see has nothing to do with autoboxing or mutability. Changing a pointer like your first step and changing an object via a pointer like your second step are entirely different things. Changing the pointer pointed it to a different object. You didn't change both pointers so they pointed to different objects. This happens regardless of mutability or boxing conversion.